# Query to derive date and rate from an input string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL server I need to derive dates and rates from  given input. Date will come after 5; and rate will come after 3; There can be multiple records of date and rate can be available in the same input (concatenate those with comma in the result).

It has 2 rows. First one with single date and rate. Second one with multiple date and rates. There can be n number of dates and rates possible within the input string. Please suggest and a simple SQL query to derive the same. I am using Microsoft SQL server 2012 only, so latest functions came after that I can't use.

Input (2 rows):

```
;2;1;2;5;20270608;3;100.000000;
;2;203;2;5;19680515;3;100.000000;5;19690515;3;100.000000;5;19700515;3;100.000000;5;19710515;3;100.000000;5;19720515;3;100.000000;
```

Output date (2 rows):

```
20270608
19680515,19690515,19700515,19710515,19720515
```

Output rate (2 rows):

```
100.000000
100.000000,100.000000,100.000000,100.000000,100.000000
```

Comment: If you split your data from semicolons into rows, and then check with lead / lag the rows and use `try_convert(date, xxx, 112)`, you should be able to find your data. Probably need to add a row number first, so you can parse it back to individual rows.

Comment: SQL is not the best tool to do this, is it not possible to do this in software that receives this data ? I guess it can be done but it will be very very very slow

Answer (score 1):

As @JamesZ already said in the comments, you can do this with the [lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function

```
declare @test varchar(1000) = ';2;203;2;5;19680515;3;100.000000;5;19690515;3;100.000000;5;19700515;3;100.000000;5;19710515;3;100.000000;5;19720515;3;100.000000;'

select string_agg(t2.nextvalue, ',')
from   ( select t.value,
                lead(value, 1) over (order by one) nextvalue
         from   ( select '1' as one,
                         value
                  from   STRING_SPLIT(@test ,';')
                  where value is not null
                  and   value <> ''
                ) t
      ) t2
where t2.value = '5'
```

the result is

```
19680515,19690515,19700515,19710515,19720515
```

To get the rates just do

```
where t2.value = '3'
```

Try it yourself [in this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=47b40c6ea273593d9159c1d371859533)

**EDIT**

Since sql server 2012 has no `split_string` function you can use the [DelimitedSplit8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) function instead

And since it also does not have the `string_agg` function we will have to use `xml` instead

And then we use [stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get rid of the extra `,` at the start

```
select stuff ( ( select ',' + t2.nextvalue
                 from   ( select t.item,
                                 lead(item, 1) over (order by one) nextvalue
                          from   ( select '1' as one,
                                          item
                                   from   DelimitedSplit8K(@test, ';')
                                   where item is not null
                                   and   item <> ''
                                 ) t
                        ) t2
                where t2.item = '5'
                for XML PATH('')
               ), 
               1, 1, ''
             ) as dates
```

[new DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7bbd8c14076e064e62c5be98d5f12a96)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Unfortunately STRING_SPLIT is not supported in my SQL version.

Comment: what version do you have ?

Comment: Not sure if this is the latest link, but I've used the delimited split 8k function in these situations: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function (a lot of text and things, but the sources are in the end)

Comment: Version 2012. It throws error SPLIT_FUNCTION is not a recognized built-in function name !

Comment: @AnoobKA That is a very old version which is not supported anymore, you will not get any updates anymore. Using this version is not recommended and will have security problems. I recommend upgrading to a later version.

Comment: @AnoobKA I edited my answer with a query that does not uses split_string and string_agg.

Comment: @AnoobKA Edited my answer again, the query for sql-server 2012 now also get's rid of the comma `,` at the start

Comment: @GuidoG Do I need to create DelimitedSplit8K function. I am not able to find any such function existing in that name. It shows invalid object name error.

Comment: @AnoobKA Yes you need to create the function `DelimitedSplit8K` to replace the missing `split_string` function

Comment: Thanks @GuidoG. I will create the function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses. I had slightly changed the response from @GuidoG and written the query without using function as below,

```
SELECT 
  string_agg(t2.nextvalue, ',') 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      t.item, 
      Lead(item, 1) OVER (
        ORDER BY 
          one
      ) nextvalue 
    from 
      (
        SELECT 
          '1' AS one, 
          item 
        from 
          (
            SELECT 
              split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS item 
            from 
              (
                SELECT 
                  cast (
                    '<m>' + replace(@test, ';', '</m><m>') + '</m>' as xml
                  ) as data
              ) AS x cross apply data.nodes ('/M') AS split(a)
          ) AS i 
        where 
          item IS NOT null 
          and item <> ''
      ) t
  ) t2 
where 
  t2.item = '5'
```